# boost graph library memory consumption large graph

Tags: boost, graph, memory-management

I have a large graph (30k vertices, 250m edges) and using boost graph library adjacency list (I tried both vecs and lists) consumes more than 25gb. since it is not very easy to get a pc with more than 16gb ram, what do you recommend to decrease memory usage ?

Comment: That's nearly a complete graph! What is the size of one node? What is actually in a node? You're not giving us much to go by.

Comment: I don't think it is practical to load the whole graph into memory for the graph size as described. Have you even consider ways like MapReduce? to process large graph?

Comment: graph has only index property on vertices and weight property on edges.

Comment: for MapReduce all algorithms should be distributed parallel in nature I guess. I dont want to enter into distributed parallel computation business if I dont need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same problem with a verification technique using graphs I'm working on.
If you will work with a huge amount of data (vertices and also edges) you should use a fine tuned data structure created by yourself.

If you have a lot of edges, you should consider using an Adjacency Matrix.
The edges have weights, so you could use something like this:

```
vector<int> vertices;
vector<vector<int> > edges;
```

You could use the optimized `vector<vector<bool> >` that uses only one bit to represent each edge, if the edges didn't have a property.

Although the adjacency matrix is fast when you want to check for an edge or add one, it's not good to iterate over edges.

I can say that, using the same properties in BGL and in my own graph, my graph is way smaller.